# React Native FlatList - when isLoading not rendering footer

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am having problems in my react native flatlist when reaching the end of the list.

The behavior I need is the typical: fetch database when end reached, showing a loading indicator at the footer during the operation.

The problem is that, for some reasons, the loading indicator is not shown.

Here is my FlatList Component:

```
    ...

    const renderFooter = () => {
        if (!props.isLoading) return null;

        return (
          <View style={{ paddingVertical: 35 }}>
             <Loading type="ios" size={30} color={colors.primary} />
          </View>
        );
    };

    return (
      <FlatList
        ref={ref}
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        windowSize={5}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
        updateCellsBatchingPeriod={50}
        removeClippedSubviews={false}
        initialNumToRender={initialNumToRender}
        ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
        ListEmptyComponent={ListEmptyComponent}
        onEndReached={onEndReached}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
        contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
      />
    );
```

And this is how I fetch the database:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
const [isGettingMoreOldItems, setIsGettingMoreOldItems] = useState(true);

const fetchItems = async (old = true) => {
   ...
   const newItems = await db.getItems();
   setItems(old ? [...items, ...newItems] : [...newItems, ...items]);
   ...
}

const getMoreOldItems = async () => {
   setIsGettingMoreOldItems(true);
   await fetchItems(); // <--------- I AM AWAITING!
   setIsGettingMoreOldItems(false);
}

 ...

return <MyList ... isLoading={isGettingMoreOldItems} onEndReached={getMoreOldItems} ... />
```

Why am I not seeing the loading indicator when the end of the list is reached and the app starts fetching the database? How can I fix this?

Note: The fetch operation lasts 2 seconds (aprox.)

### CURIOSITY

If I do:

```
const getMoreOldItems = async () => {
   setIsGettingMoreOldItems(true);
   await fetchItems(); // <--------- I AM AWAITING!

   setTimeout(() => {
      setIsGettingMoreOldItems(false);
   }, 1000);
}
```

I can see the footer. But seems a bit tricky and not clear...

Comment: I think the code is not waiting because the `const getMoreOldItems` is a promise. Check this two links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57922556/asyncawait-is-not-waiting-for-the-fetch-response and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823277/async-await-not-working-in-combination-with-fetch

Comment: @noszone but whats the problem with that? I mean, if getMoreOldItems is awaiting fetchItems before updating state, right?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the code inside:

```
const getMoreOldItems = async () => {
   setIsGettingMoreOldItems(true);
   await fetchItems(); // <--------- I AM AWAITING!
   setIsGettingMoreOldItems(false);
}
```

should be like this:

```
const getMoreOldItems = async () => {
   await setIsGettingMoreOldItems(true);
   await fetchItems(); // <--------- I AM AWAITING!
   await setIsGettingMoreOldItems(false);
}
```

Second thing that please always remember that all JS is async D:.

Also possible to use an anonymous function if above will not will work:

```
(async () => {
await setIsGettingMoreOldItems(true);
await fetchItems(); // <--------- I AM AWAITING!
await setIsGettingMoreOldItems(false);
})();
```

**Update:**

`await` is only useful if you use it with a promise, but requests (in your case a fetch) does not return a promise. It doesn't have a return statement at all, so it's implicitly returning undefined.

So simply just do the following after each fetch:

```
let data = await response.json(); // or similar upon your needs - blob, etc
```

In your case it will be something like:

```
let data = await newItems.json();
```

Comment: It's not possible to await a useState setter. Also, it throws a warning: "await has no effect on the type of this expression."

Comment: Also, the async/await of the original code works. The error comes from somewhere unexpected.

Comment: But yes, state updates are async, but cannot be handled as promises. Instead, the correct way is to use a custom hook.

Comment: Because your fetch doesn't have a reponse. See updated answer.

Comment: Doesn't work man. It is not necessary to save the result of an await in a variable.

Comment: Just recently I got same case fought. I would needed to update a status of download button (spinner) in depend of blob downloaded (4 sec). And it works only after I checked everything. Check your code step by step.